# Replace Variable for Installer with User Input

Tags: macos, bash, shell, variables, terminal

I have .pkg that requires user input for a variable that is required for install.

```
API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" installer -pkg /prey-0.6.2-mac-batch.mpkg -target /
```

The user puts the API_KEY in the quotes and installer runs fine, without it fails. I've attempted to make a script that request input for variable and runs installer.

Attempt 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

API_KEY="$INPUT_API_KEY"

read -p "Please input your API KEY:" INPUT_API_KEY

installer -pkg /prey-0.6.2-mac-batch.mpkg -target /
```

Attempt 2:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please input your API KEY:" INPUT_API_KEY

API_KEY="$INPUT_API_KEY" installer -pkg /prey-0.6.2-mac-batch.mpkg -target /
```

when I use the API_KEY= in this context command line spits out error saying API_KEY is not a valid command, but I know that. What am I doing wrong? ANY input is appreciated :) no pun intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get why your attempt 2 wouldn't work. I don't see why the shell would try to execute `API_KEY=` as a command there, when it's clearly a variable assignment for the environment of the `installer`.

Anyway, if you write like this (equivalently to your attempt 2), what error message will it give you? (This should rule out the earlier one...)

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please input your API KEY:" INPUT_API_KEY
export API_KEY="$INPUT_API_KEY"
installer -pkg /prey-0.6.2-mac-batch.mpkg -target /
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention attempt 3 lol I used export but it was my first line after interpreter

Comment: still getting invalid API_KEY

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is werid how attempt two doesn't work.

Comment: @Geofferey yeah. Maybe somebody might know and comment later ;-)